# error while updating to Joomla 3.6.0

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

while updating to Joomla 3.6.0 this error occurred:

```
Duplicate column name 'last_check_timestamp' SQL=ALTER TABLE `#__update_sites` ADD COLUMN `last_check_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' AFTER `enabled`;
```

i had the same error while updating to Joomla 3.5.1

what is this? and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates/mysql/2.5.0-2011-12-06.sql`.

Remove this line:

```
`ALTER TABLE  `#__update_sites` ADD COLUMN `last_check_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' AFTER `enabled`;`
```

Save the file and try redoing the update.

Comment: Could be possible that you're not using MySQL, but instead `postgresql` or `sqlazure`, in which case, you'd need to edit the correct file that corresponds to your database engine

Comment: no, im using mysql. i saw the line in the file that itoctopus said, and i deleted it. but it didn't work..

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17241/error-while-updating-to-joomla-3-6-0